# How to place text with tikz under beamer at an absolute position on the slide

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, positioning

I want to place some text on a `beamer` slide next to a figure. The problem is that if I simply use `tikzpicture` environment, LaTeX places the text *after* whatever is placed before, be it hidden or shown. How can I tell `tikz` to use page coordinates and not count whatever it counts from the current position?

**Edit:**
Minimal working example. Apparently, this has something to do with my choose of columns.

```
\documentclass[bigger]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.6\textwidth}
      \only <1>{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \node at (0,0) {a};
        \end{tikzpicture}
      }
      \only <2>{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \node at (0,0) {b};
        \end{tikzpicture}
      }
      \only <3>{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \node at (0,0) {c};
        \end{tikzpicture}
      }
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

When I compile this, 'a', 'b', and 'c' doesn't appear on the same place but rather one after the other .

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Jubobs I've added MWE. Sorry.

Comment: You have spurious spaces at the ends of your `\only` invocations.  End them with `}%` instead of `}`

Answer (score 1):

Your text contains spaces that are outside of the scope of the `\only` commands, namely the newlines after the final brace of `\only{...}`.  To remove these you need to add a final `%` sign:

```
\only<1>{...
...}%
```

Your complete code will then be something like:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[bigger]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.6\textwidth}
      \only <1>{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \node at (0,0) {a};
        \end{tikzpicture}
      }%
      \only <2>{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \node at (0,0) {b};
        \end{tikzpicture}
      }%
      \only <3>{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \node at (0,0) {c};
        \end{tikzpicture}
      }
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```